# mysqli code will not send to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have searched on here tirlessly and can not seen to find a solution to getting my code to work, i am trying to create a simple sign up system for member to join my website but i can not seen to get my php code to send to the database i have set up, here is the code.

```
<?php require 'lpgamers/connections/connect.php'; ?>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Register'])) {

        session_start();
        $FName = $_POST['First_Name'];
        $LName = $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $PW = $_POST['Password'];

        $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO lpg-user-db (Fname, Lname, Email, Password)Values('{$FName}', '{$LName}', '{$Email}', '{$PW}')");
    }
?>
        <div class="rightbody">
          <form id="registerform" name="registerform" method="post">
            <div class="formelement">
                <input name="First_Name" type="text" required class="tfield" id="First_Name" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="formelement">
                <input name="Last_Name" type="text" required class="tfield" id="Last_Name" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="formelement">
                <input name="Email" type="email" required class="tfield" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="formelement">
                <input name="Password" type="password" required class="tfield" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="formelement">
                <input name="Register" type="submit" class="button" id="Register" value="Register">
            </div>
          </form>
```

I also have a connect file that is required and i have this set up and this does connect to my database

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lpgamers-user-db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf('Connect failed: %s\n', mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

?>
```

am i doing somthing wrong here or is this just a database problem, i am using a wamp server at this moment for testing ?.

Thanks in advance Rob.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
 Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Check your error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_error($con)` should have thrown you an error for this, but you didn't check for errors.

Your `lpg-user-db` table in

```
INSERT INTO lpg-user-db
```

contains hyphens and MySQL is interpreting that as `lpg MINUS user MINUS db`, in thinking you want it to do math.

The table name would require to have ticks around it:

```
INSERT INTO `lpg-user-db`
```

Either do that, or replace them with underscores and renaming it:

```
INSERT INTO lpg_user_db
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Sidenote: If there are any constraints in your table, `mysqli_error($con)` will inform you of it.

If the data you are trying to input contains characters that MySQL will complain about and for example `John's Bar & Grill`, then you will need to escape your data; something you should be doing anyway.

```
$FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['First_Name']);
```

and doing the same for the other POST arrays.

You're also open to an SQL injection, use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much Fred -ii-. this has worked and has got all my info sending over, i am slowley getting there and will be doing somthing about my security soon. Thanks Again Rob